# How to make Gstreamer return only keyframes?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp, rtsp-client

In `gstreamer` pipeline, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to specify that **I only want key frames from a RTSP stream**.

In `ffmpeg` you can do this with with `-skip_frame nokey` flag. E.g.:

`ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov -qscale 0 -r 1/1 frame%03d.jpg`

The corresponding gstreamer command to read the RTSP feed looks like this:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov ! decodebin ! videorate ! "video/x-raw,framerate=1/1" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

Does anyone know if it is possible to ask gstreamer to only return keyframes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could try add `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER` pad probe and return `GST_PAD_PROBE_DROP` on buffers with `GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DELTA_UNIT` flag set.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how do i add it to the gst-launch pipeline?

Comment: unfortunately it's possible only in code I think. gst-launch is intended to be only some sort of quick test tool, not fully functional application as ffmpeg.

Answer (score 5):

After spending days looking for a complete answer to this question, I eventually ended up with a solution that gave me the rtsp processing boost I was looking for.

Here is the diff of a pipeline in Python that transitioned from processing every RTSP frame to only processing key frames.

https://github.com/ambianic/ambianic-edge/pull/171/files#diff-f89415777c559bba294250e788230c5e

First register for the stream start bus event:

```
Gst.MessageType.STREAM_START
```

This is triggered when the stream processing starts. When this event occurs, request seek to the next keyframe.

When the request completes, the pipeline triggers the next bus event we need to listen for:

```
Gst.MessageType.ASYNC_DONE
```

Finally, here is the keyframe seek request itself:

```py
    def _gst_seek_next_keyframe(self):
        found, pos_int = self.gst_pipeline.query_position(Gst.Format.TIME)
        if not found:
            log.warning('Gst current pipeline position not found.')
            return
        rate = 1.0  # keep rate close to real time
        flags = \
            Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH | Gst.SeekFlags.KEY_UNIT | \
            Gst.SeekFlags.TRICKMODE | Gst.SeekFlags.SNAP_AFTER | \
            Gst.SeekFlags.TRICKMODE_KEY_UNITS | \
            Gst.SeekFlags.TRICKMODE_NO_AUDIO
        is_event_handled = self.gst_pipeline.seek(
            rate,
            Gst.Format.TIME,
            flags,
            Gst.SeekType.SET, pos_int,
            Gst.SeekType.END, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a new seek event `gst_event_new_seek` with the flag `GstSeekFlags` for trickmode `GST_SEEK_FLAG_TRICKMODE`, skip frames `GST_SEEK_FLAG_SKIP` and keyframes only `GST_SEEK_FLAG_TRICKMODE_KEY_UNITS`.

You can also use `identity` and its property `drop-buffer-flags` to filter for `GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DELTA_UNIT` and maybe `GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DROPPABLE`.

see [trickmodes](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/trickmodes.html), [seeking](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/seeking.html) and [GstSeekFlags](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstEvent.html#GstSeekFlags) in the documentation for the seeking and [identity:drop-buffer-flags](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-identity.html#GstIdentity--drop-buffer-flags) and [GstBufferFlags](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBuffer.html#GstBufferFlags) for identity.